# Exit Maps Navigation and resume Xamarin Forms Android app in single tap

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, xamarin.forms

I launched Google Maps Navigation from my Xamarin Forms app using Intents, and intend to exit Navigation and return to my app with a single tap. I have been looking for a solution to make exit work, but couldn't so far.

Below is what I have on my mind:

- I can launch a background service and a floating icon while launching the Intent. Tapping on floating button could launch back my application, but it seems it would launch from scratch each time. Is it possible to resume my app instead?
- I understand that Navigation can only work from Google Maps app and not from the Maps Webapp. Is there a workaround for this as I can insert Maps Webapp in my App Webview?
- Is there any other custom maps available (Open Source or Paid) which can fulfill above requirements?

Appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use dependence service to call `Intent intent = PackageManager.GetLaunchIntentForPackage(packName);Context.StartActivity(intent);` in your Android, to open the background application by package name. I do not know which function do you want to achieve it in map, here is a map plugin, you can check it, if it support the function that you needed.https://github.com/amay077/Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT I am not really able to corelate your answer to my question, but I can confirm that I am looking for turn-by-turn navigation which is only available through Maps app it seems.

Comment: You would need to Query the Google Directions API and display a Polyline on a Map in your app https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/start  Use GPS to track the user location on the path and use the Text To Speech API to talk to the user.